# Fastapi showing error on inserting data on mysql table

Tags: python, mysql, fastapi, pydantic

[image]

`

```
@user.post("/add-user")
async def write_user_date(user: User):

    conn.execute(users.insert().values(
        name=user.name,
        email=user.email,
        password=user.password,
    ))
    return conn.execute(users.select()).fetchall()
```

`

That is my code, but every time when I post a data it's show

`ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\users\hp\desktop\fastapi project\venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\encoders.py", line 152, in jsonable_encoder data = dict(obj) TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence`

this error. How to resolve it?

this error. How to resolve it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Convert your data to dictonary first for example `data = user.dict()`, then you can get the values from dictionary and insert it in your database.

On side note never store passwords as it is, always hash your passwords you can use `from passlib.context import CryptContext`. This makes easier to hash and verify the hash.

Comment: even it's not working on get method!!
I used many times this code for all others project where it works. 

@our_user.get('/')
async def fetch_users():
    return conn.execute(tbl_users.select()).fetchall()

Answer (score 0):

**Hello I solved this issue by changing my virtual environment**
This issue created from virtual environment, lib folder.